# PHP: Dynamically call default method

Tags: php, class, dynamic, methods

There's the following (example) class:

```
class klasse
{
    private $var = 'doit';

    function doit($param)
    {
        return md5($param);
    }
    function bla($param)
    {
        // HERES THE PROBLEM
        return $this->{$this->var}($param);
    }
}

// Create new instance
$klasse = new klasse;

// Start the "dynamical output"
echo $klasse->bla('test');
```

This works fine! But the problem is that I'd like to call the md5() function "directly dynamically". So I don't want to go the detour with "doit()".
If I try

```
private $var = 'md5';
```

at the beginning of the class I get the following (absolutely senseful) error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method klasse::md5() in - on line 13

So I know that this error is senseful but I have no clue how to avoid it?

How can I handle this (to directly call md5())?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Anyway, how about something like: `$func = 'md5';$func();`  Remember that`md5()` is not a method of `klass`.

Comment: Becaues there's an API where I can set a hash algorithm as parameter (actually it is sha1 and not md5, this is only for testing purposes).
Your suggestion works not in a class. That's my problem.

Your edit is quite important - of course it is not a method of klasse. How can I call it anyway?

Comment: maybe , `if method_exist($this, method_name) ? $this->method_name() else do_nth` ??

Comment: But then I'd need to create a function for every possible parameter. Isn't this possible directly?

Comment: I actually dont understand what you are trying to do so I just shoot out what it make sense to me lol.. so I guess it will just pass to someone else

Comment: Oh, ok, then sorry for the bad explanation:
I have a class with a method. This method should call a default PHP-function (here: md5()) directly. The name of the function that I want to be called should be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class klasse
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->var = 'md5';
    }


}

$klasse = new klasse;
echo call_user_func($klasse->var, 'argument');
```

More info at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: Thank you, I know this function. But I thought I was possible without it. If nobody has another solution, I need to use this. Thanks anyway!